# Как сделать сборку общей для всех доменов?

Tags: .net

Есть тяжеловесная сборка, которая подгружается во все домены .NET приложения.
Как сделать её общей для всех доменов, чтобы она грузилась в процесс один раз?

Answer (score 3):

Зависит от того, что подразумевается под "загружаться". По умолчанию сборки загружаются с диска в память только один раз. Это можно проверить в окне Debug/Windows/Modules - сборка будет упомянута несколько раз, но значение в колонке Address для нее будет одним и тем же для разных доменов.

Если этого недостаточно, то можно:

- Отметить точку входа вашего приложения как `[LoaderOptimization(LoaderOptimization.MultiDomain)]` - это позволит максимально [шарить загруженные ресурсы между доменами](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.loaderoptimization(v=vs.110).aspx). Под шарингом ресурсов подразумевается:

  - возможность дополнительным доменам использовать готовые native image - результаты предварительного прохода NGEN.
  - шаринг результатов JIT.
- Установить сборку в GAC и прогнать ее NGEN-ом - это тогда сборка будет загружаться в память не только один раз для различных AppDomain но и один раз для одновременно запущенных приложений, которые ее испольуют. Это обычный подход при хостинге большого количества одинаковых приложений - например, одинаковых сайтов на одном сервере.

Comment: Когда говорят о «тяжёлой» сборке, имеется в виду обычно не размер (виртуальная память научилась хорошо с этим справляться), а время инициализации, то есть пробег статических конструкторов. Это таким образом оптимизировать не удастся.

Comment: Первый раз вижу упоминание "тяжелая" в этом смысле. У меня после глобальных мер вида ngen для пачки сайтов время старта упало с 2 минут до 5 секунд. JIT из них занимал секунд 20. Причем сборки были тупо тяжелыми по объему (несколько штук по 10-20 мегабайт). Сайты - это домены в одном процессе. Не могу представить чтобы статические конструкторы работали сравнимое с этим время (это уже совсем плохо с архитектурой, закопать и забыть)

Comment: Попробуйте запустить на слабой машине серьёзное WPF-приложение после рестарта системы, вы будете удивлены.

Comment: @Vlad вот поэтому WPF так непопулярен. Но тем не менее - проблема подгрузки сборки - это не только проблема статических конструкторов. Пусть TC решает что у него там тормозит, и оптимизирует соответственно.

Comment: WPF популярен в мире, где у людей быстрые компьютеры. То есть сейчас практически везде, где люди платят за софт. Но это офтопик. А проблема у WPF именно со статической инициализацией, насколько я понимаю.

Answer (score 1):

По идее, никак, `AppDomain`'ы изолированы друг от друга.

Возможно, вы сможете *обойти* проблему тем, что загрузите эту сборку только в *один* `AppDomain`, и будете маршаллировать вызовы в него? Учтите, что это может оказаться медленнее, чем таки загрузить сборку в каждый `AppDomain`, тестируйте!